# Trouble with Coffeescript Indent

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to translate this into Coffeescript:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend(InfiniteScroll.ViewMixin, {
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.setupInfiniteScrollListener();
  },
  willDestroyElement: function(){
    this.teardownInfiniteScrollListener();
  }
});
```

My first approach was this:

```
Whistlr.OrganizationsView = Em.View.extend
  InfiniteScroll.ViewMixin
  didInsertElement: ->
    @setupInfiniteScrollListener()
  willDestroyElement: ->
    @teardownInfiniteScrollListener()
```

But it threw an unexpected indent error. So I tried this instead:

```
Whistlr.OrganizationsView = Em.View.extend InfiniteScroll.ViewMixin
  didInsertElement: ->
    @setupInfiniteScrollListener()
  willDestroyElement: ->
    @teardownInfiniteScrollListener()
```

Which gives me this error:

```
TypeError: InfiniteScroll.ViewMixin is not a function
```

If I use the plain js, it works fine. So the problem is definitely with the Coffeescript formatting. I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on, or even how to properly search for an explanation. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/try-coffeescript-enhanced/fldhkfldchaibgaheaogapecjmnkaepe?hl=en -- this is helpful for converting js to coffee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Whistlr.OrganizationsView = Em.View.extend InfiniteScroll.ViewMixin,
  didInsertElement: -> @setupInfiniteScrollListener()
  willDestroyElement: -> @teardownInfiniteScrollListener()
```

The second parameter of `.extend` needs to be an JavaScript object.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error: `TypeError: InfiniteScroll.ViewMixin is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. Looks like I was missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick translation of the JS to Coffeescript.  When I paste it into the 'Try Coffeescript' browser window, it produces the same JS (with added returns).  The extra (){} are for my benefit, not CS's.  They make it clear to me that this is a call to `extend`, with 2 arguments, one an object attribute, the other an object with two function definitions.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend(
    InfiniteScroll.ViewMixin,
    {
    didInsertElement: ()  ->
        @setupInfiniteScrollListener()
    willDestroyElement: () ->
        @teardownInfiniteScrollListener()
    }
)
```